# Anonymous PartialFunction syntax

Tags: scala, partialfunction, partial-functions

I asked this question earlier: [Combine a PartialFunction with a regular function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357710/combine-a-partialfunction-with-a-regular-function/38359355)

and then realized, that I haven't actually asked it right. 
So, here goes another attempt.

If I do this:

```
 val foo = PartialFunction[Int, String] { case 1 => "foo" }
 val bar = foo orElse { case x => x.toString }
```

it does not compile: `error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: PartialFunction[?,?]`

But this works fine:

```
   val x: Seq[String] = List(1,2,3).collect { case x => x.toString }
```

The question is what is the difference? The type of the argument is the same in both cases: `PartialFunction[Int, String]`. The value passed in is literally identical. Why one does one case work, but not the other?

Comment: `collect` expects an `PartialFunction[A, B]` while `orElse` expects an `[A1 <: A, B1 >: B] PartialFunction[A1, B1]`, so while the compiler can infer the first, you somehow need to help with the second.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterNeyens, that explains it for me. Post it as an answer is you care about 25 points rep. bump :)

Comment: You can add @PeterNeyens answer and accept it so it can be easily found and people don't need to go through the comments as I did.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type for `bar` because the compiler is unable to infer it. This compiles:

```
val foo = PartialFunction[Int, String] { case 1 => "foo" }
val bar : (Int => String) = foo orElse { case x => x.toString }
```

Comment: In this case the ```orElse``` method that gets called is in Function rather than PartialFunction. That illustrates another ambiguity around this that you wouldn't want the compiler to just assume. I'm not sure that the OP wants a Function in the end.

Comment: @ScottShipp are you sure? where is `orElse` in `Function`? And what does it do?

Comment: @henrik, I realize it is unable to infer it. The question was _why_ it is unable to infer it, and why it is able to infer it in the other case.

Comment: @Dima `orElse` is a method in the `PartialFunction` trait and has type bounds `[A1 <: A, B1 >: B]`, in this case `A` is `Int`, and `B` is `String`. Because `B1` is only lower bounded by type `String`, it can't infer the actual type that you want.

Comment: Yeah, I got that from @PeterNeyens comment earlier. Too bad he didn't post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `List(1,2,3).collect{case x => x.toString}` the compiler is able to infer the input type of the partial function based off of how the`List` was typed.

```
final override def collect[B, That](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That])
```

Based on the type parameters the compiler can infer that you are passing a correctly typed partial function. That's why `List(1,2,3).collect{case x:String => x.toString}` does not compile nor does `List(1,2,3).collect{case x:Int => x.toString; case x: String => x.toString}`.

Since `List` is covariant the compiler is able to infer that the partial function `{case x => x.toString}` is a partial function on `Int`. You'll notice that `List(1,2,3).collect{case x => x.length}` does not compile because the compiler is inferring that you're operating on either an `Int` or a subclass of `Int`.

Also keep in mind that the `{case x => x.toString}` is just syntactic sugar. If we do something like the below then your example works as expected

```
val f = new PartialFunction[Int, String](){
  override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = true
  override def apply(v1: Int): String = v1.toString
}

val foo = PartialFunction[Int, String] { case 1 => "foo" }

val bar = foo orElse f //This compiles fine.

List(1,2,3).collect{f} // This works as well.
```

So the only logical answer from my perspective is that the syntactic sugar that is able to generate a `PartialFunction` instance for `{case x => x.toString}` does not have enough information at compile time to be able to adequately type it as a `PartialFunction[Int, String]` in your `orElse` case.

Comment: This is not the perfect solution, because you did not implement `applyOrElse`. `applyOrElse` will improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [Extractor.scala](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/Extractor.scala).

```
import com.thoughtworks.Extractor._

// Define a PartialFunction
val pf: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 1 => "matched by PartialFunction"
}

// Define an optional function
val f: Int => Option[String] = { i =>
  if (i == 2) {
    Some("matched by optional function")
  } else {
    None
  }
}

// Convert an optional function to a PartialFunction
val pf2: PartialFunction[Int, String] = f.unlift

util.Random.nextInt(4) match {
  case pf.extract(m) => // Convert a PartialFunction to a pattern
    println(m)
  case f.extract(m) => // Convert an optional function to a pattern
    println(m)
  case pf2.extract(m) => // Convert a PartialFunction to a pattern
    throw new AssertionError("This case should never occur because it has the same condition as `f.extract`.")
  case _ =>
    println("Not matched")
}
```