# scala: anonymous partial function strange syntax

Tags: scala

I came across a code similar to this, and it was surprised that it even compiles:

```
scala> val halfSize: PartialFunction[String, Int] = _.length match {
    case even if even % 2 == 0 => even / 2 
}
halfSize: PartialFunction[String,Int] = <function1>

scala> List("x", "xx").collect(halfSize)
res1: List[Int] = List(1)
```

As far as I known, the valid syntax to define a `PartialFunction` is a case function:

```
val halfSize: PartialFunction[String, Int] = { 
     case s if s.length % 2 == 0 => s.length / 2 
}
```

The first code seems more optimized since it calls `length` only once. But even in the SLS I was not able to find the explanation of the syntax. Is this an undocumented feature of scalac ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules are given in https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions:

> The eventual run-time value of an anonymous function is determined by the expected type:
>
> - ...
> - `PartialFunction[T, U]`, if the function literal is of the shape `x => x match { … }`

In this case the literal <s>does have such a shape, as rogue-one's answer explains, so `PartialFunction` is allowed as the expected type.</s>

(EDIT: actually, it doesn't, since it matches `x.length` instead of `x`. This looks like a minor bug, but one which should be fixed by changing the specification.)

> A PartialFunction's value receives an additional isDefinedAt member, which is derived from the pattern match in the function literal, with each case's body being replaced by true, and an added default (if none was given) that evaluates to false.

So in this case it ends up with

```
def isDefinedAt(x: String) = x.length match {
  case even if even % 2 == 0 => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the relevant part of the spec. What actually surprised is exactly what you added in your EDIT (in the original code, `x.length` was a more elaborated statement).

Comment: And so we agree this is an undocumented feature ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
val halfSize: PartialFunction[String, Int] = _.length match {
    case even if even % 2 == 0 => even / 2 
}
```

The underscore (`_`) in the above function is just a short hand notation that refers to the single argument of the function. Thus the above snippet is just a short form of

```
val halfSize: PartialFunction[String, Int] = { (x: String) => x.length match {
    case even if even % 2 == 0 => even / 2 
 }
}
```

Comment: but even in the expanded version, it should give a `Function`, not a `PartialFunction`

Comment: thats because PartialFunction[A,B] extends Function[A,B] as shown here http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/PartialFunction.html

Comment: Function is higher is the inheritance, so it can't be assigned to a PartialFunction

Comment: take a look at this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930698/why-is-partialfunction-function-in-scala

Comment: Quoting the answer: A PartialFunction is just a Function that promises to tell you where it's not defined. In my case, how the compiler infers the `isDefined` method is black magic to me (or at least undocumented)

Comment: @pedrofurla This 1) would work incorrectly for functions which have side effects; 2) would be slow if function does a lot of work to calculate the result just to throw it away.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I guess you are right, it used to be like that a long long time ago.